# \newrefformat not working in the definition of \newenvironment

Tags: cross-referencing, environments

Getting inspired by this [Have reference in section with custom counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507638/have-reference-in-section-with-custom-counter?rq=1), I've developed the following new environment. All is fine except when I call `\prettyref{dog:1}` output is just showing **1** instead of **DOG1**. After some amount of debugging, it looks like `\newrefformat` inside the definition of the environment is not being executed.

```
\newenvironment{animals}[1][dog]%
{
    \newrefformat{#1}{\hyperref[{##1}]{\uppercase{#1} \ref*{##1}}}
    
    \newcount\IndexNum
    \IndexNum = 1
    \newcounter{count#1}%
    \setcounter{count#1}{0}%
    
    \let\olditem\item%
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\texttt{\uppercase{#1}\arabic*}}, ref={\arabic*}]%
    
        \setcounter{enumi}{\value{count#1}}%
        \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
            \refstepcounter{count#1}\olditem%
            \label{#1:\the\IndexNum} \global\advance\IndexNum by 1
        }%

}%
{\end{enumerate}}
```

I've also attached an MWE for your reference.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{prettyref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{animals}[1][dog]%
{
    \newrefformat{#1}{\hyperref[{##1}]{\uppercase{#1} \ref*{##1}}}
    
    \newcount\IndexNum
    \IndexNum = 1
    \newcounter{count#1}%
    \setcounter{count#1}{0}%
    
    \let\olditem\item%
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\texttt{\uppercase{#1}\arabic*}}, ref={\arabic*}]%
        
        \setcounter{enumi}{\value{count#1}}%
        \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
            \refstepcounter{count#1}\olditem%
            \label{#1:\the\IndexNum} \global\advance\IndexNum by 1
        }%
        
    }%
    {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{animals}
        \item Pitbull
        \item Boxer
    \end{animals}

\prettyref{dog:1} is Pitbull. 
\end{document}
```

Current output is

[image: Current output]

while the expected output is

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\newrefformat` command effect is limited in scope by the environment.

Looking at the source code in `prettyref` package, one discovers it is possible to prefix it by `\global` to overcome the scope limitation.

Besides, despite its name, it will not as `\newcommand` raise an error if reused with same argument.  So one can have multiple such environments with same optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{prettyref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{animals}[1][dog]{%
    \global\newrefformat{#1}{\hyperref[{##1}]{\uppercase{#1}\ref*{##1}}}%
%    
    \newcount\IndexNum
    \IndexNum = 1
    \newcounter{count#1}%
    \setcounter{count#1}{0}%
%    
    \let\olditem\item
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\texttt{\uppercase{#1}\arabic*}}, ref={\arabic*}]
        
        \setcounter{enumi}{\value{count#1}}%
        \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
            \refstepcounter{count#1}\olditem%
            \label{#1:\the\IndexNum} \global\advance\IndexNum by 1
        }%
        
    }%
    {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{animals}
        \item Pitbull
        \item Boxer
    \end{animals}

\prettyref{dog:1} is Pitbull. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.!!

Comment: @ShastriD The code has important faults in particular `\newcount\IndexNum` should better NOT be part of environment, you only need to reset the count to `1` at each use.  As per the `\newcounter`it is surprising to include it ias this will limit to one use only of environment with given argument: `LaTeX Error: Command \c@countdog already defined.`  It looks very strange to have to use both a `\count` and a LaTeX counter, something clearly is sub-optimal. An "environment" that one can use only once, is not really a genuine environment, it does not look like the correct structure for your task

Comment: Thank you for pointing the mistake. I've now put an if condition to check if the counter is already defined. If so, I'll only reset the counter. Now it lets using the environment multiple tiles for the same argument.